# How to pass two components with a conditions to a single route (<route/>) method in react jsx?

Tags: reactjs

(
Passing two components with a conditions to a single route () method in react jsx?

.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you only need to add a ternary expression. If the condition is true, you will render Component1. If it is false, you will render Component2.

```
<Route path="/your_pathname_here">
    {condition ? <Component1 /> : <Component2 />}
</Route>
```

I am assuming here that you are using react-router. It is unclear what routing you are using, since you did not add that information in your question.